# My Router doesn't work after migration of Swift and update of Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I'm doing the migration of my app on Swift 2.0. I took the opportunity to also migrate Alamofire from 1.3 to 2.0.

But now my app is not working anymore, and i got many errors on the file where i use Alamofire.

First on my enum Router declaration i got an error who say

```
private enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
```

EDIT: Here is the beginning of the methods that implement

> URLRequestConvertible

```
    // MARK: URLRequestConvertible

    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let URL = Router.baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.path)
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        URLRequest.HTTPMethod = self.method.rawValue

        switch self {
        case .Login(let email, let password):
            return self.encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: [
                "email": email,
                "password": password]).0

        case .Logout:
            return self.encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: nil).0
}
```

> Type 'Router' does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'

Second in all my request when i'm gonna check the `.responseJSON { (_, _, json, error) in` i got an error who say

> Tuple types '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result)' (aka
>   '(Optional, Optional, Result)') and '(_, _, _, _)' have a different
>   number of elements (3 vs. 4)

EDIT: Ok no more `error field` but how do you do your error handling so ?

EDIT2: Ok got it now you need do use a switch for the Result. Thx

Error that i didn't had before

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Post your `Router` class code, only the methods that implement `URLRequestConvertible` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

For the second error refer to the `Alamofire` page here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

As you can see they changed the `.responseJSON` which now returns just 3 parameters. In version 1.3 there were 4 parameters instead. Basically you simply have to delete the `error` field in this way

```
.responseJSON { (_, _, json) in
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return 'NSMutableURLRequest' instead of 'NSURLRequest' if you havent changed that already.